# Can I use conditioned alert in php which is encoded in .html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am developing a page in which on adding field data on that page i want alert which is i am putting a alert msg in php code .I want an alert in my html page. I have put alert message in php tag but it is not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <? if(isset($_GET['succ'])) {
        $message1 = "Name is correct";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
    }
    if(isset($_GET['err'])) {
        $message2 = "Name is not Saurabh";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
    }
    <form action="action.php" method="post">
        First name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="firstname">
        <br>
        Last name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="lastname">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <p>If you click the "Submit" button, the form-data will be sent to a page</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Inside form action you specified `action.php` and here you are trying to get the values in the same page?

Comment: Are you getting `succ` and/or `err` in URL?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `$message1` or `$message2` instead of using **$message**.

Also, you need to close your `PHP tags` before opening any HTML element(`form` in your case).

Let your page URL has `succ` or `err` in URL parameter.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['succ'])){
        $message1 = "Name is correct";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('".$message1."');</script>";// use $message1 not $message
    } else if(isset($_GET['err'])){ // adding else, as URL only contains succ or err
        $message2 = "Name is not Saurabh";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('".$message2."');</script>";// use $message2 not $message
    }
?>
<form .....
 ....
 ....
```

Comment: @anushri, try my updated answer. Hope your problem get solved from this.